# Iterating over every two elements in a list in Python

Tags: python, list, iteration

How do I iterate over all pair combination in a list, like:

```
list = [1,2,3,4]
```

Output:

```
1,2
1,3
1,4
2,3
2,4
3,4
```

Thanks!

Comment: Using for loops and slicing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> lst = [1,2,3,4]
>>> for x in itertools.combinations(lst, 2):
...     print(x)
...
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
(1, 4)
(2, 3)
(2, 4)
(3, 4)
```

BTW, don't use `list` as a  variable name. It shadows the builtin function/type `list`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `itertools.combinations`

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.combinations([1,2,3,4], 2))
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)]
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use a nested for loop as follows:

```
list = [1,2,3,4]
for x in list :

    for y in list :

        print x, y
```

Comment: This will produce the Cartesian product instead (e.g. you'll get (1,1) and (3,1) and (4,4)).